# create a dialog using menu in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating a popupmenu(org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus) in my eclipse plugin. Now I want to launch one textfield or dialog to take user input. And on based on input I will run my run method associated with the popupMenu. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

In it's most basic interaction, you could use `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.openQuestion(Shell, String, String)` to have the user answer a yes/no question.

If you'd like them to enter a string, you can use `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.InputDialog`.  After it's closed, `getValue()` returns their input.